# Search best practice for claims based authorization with lot of permissions asp net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, webapi, claims

i'm working with the security in my application with asp net core webAPI, in my application the Admin create a new user with permission and the json send to back look like this:

```
User: {
     Name:"Alex",
     SurName:"Park",
     Email: "Alex@gmail.com",
Permission: {
    EditEmployee: true,
    DeleteEmployee: true,
    CreateEmployee: false,
    EditClient: true,
    DeleteClient: true,
    CreateClient: false,
    .....
    ...... // more than 15 other permission
}
}
```

in my DB i have the table user: have RoleId foreign Key
Table Role have  alll role of users
and table UserClaims which saved UserId with all the permission Value, type
My questions is : if i Add policy in the service in startup i must define all the policy ; more 15, and i think is lot

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("EmployeeEdit", policy => policy.RequireClaim("EditEmployee"));
    ...
    ... // SAME WORK WITH THE OTHER CLAIMS
    });
```

i ask if there are good practice for minimize the code,
thanks

Comment: your input is a collection of claims. So if that input is from in-memory (e.g: a ***literal*** `List<>`), that means you still need to type all the claim names (initializing the List), the code then is still not minified much. The policy names should be known beforehand (so that can be applied using attributes), so looks like you have no better choice. Unless you have some way to apply the policies ***dynamically at runtime***, the code adding them may be worth being minified. Minifying your code means ***minifying the input*** in this case.

Comment: by ***minifying the input***, I mean instead of using ***literal*** `List<>`, you can load them from somewhere (e.g: db, service, ...) so the code can be minified to just one line (of calling). This way you still need the corresponding list of policy names. If they are not saved somewhere you can load later, they must be derived from the claim names (e.g: using naming convention). Otherwise you have no choice, still have to manually hardcode all the names right in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create authorization policy through `AuthorizationPolicyProvider`. But the claims also need to be provided.

Customize an `AuthorizationPolicyProvider`, it can get policyname, we can create the policy according to the policyname.

```
   public class CustomAuthorizepolicyProvider : DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider
   {
    public CustomAuthorizepolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options):base(options)
    {

    }
    public override Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        //generate the authorization policy
        var claims= new List<string> 
        {
          // give 15 claims, or get the claims from database
        };

        foreach(var claim in claims)
        {
            if (claim == policyName)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireClaim(claim).Build());
            }
        }
        
        return base.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
    }
   }
```

**Note: register `CustomAuthorizepolicyProvider` as a singleton in service.**

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider,CustomAuthorizepolicyProvider>();
```